# bash tab completion - do not reprint options + prompt

Tags: bash, tab-completion

When doing tab-completion within bash (e.g. `cd dir_ <TAB>`), subsequent hits of <kbd>Tab</kbd> cause the list of matching options to be re-printed, once per hit of the Tab key (picture below). Each new line is me hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> once, and the options (and prompt) re-printed.

[image: bash tab completion]

Now, in zsh for example, this behavior is disabled. In the picture below, I have typed `cd dir_` and then hit tab REPEATEDLY. As desired, the prompt and the available completion options do not re-print, but just stay as-is, below the current prompt.

[image: zsh tab completio]

Is this at all possible with bash? The screen filling up with all the options when repeatedly hitting Tab is quite annoying.

**EDIT**
3 years later and i'm happy to report i'm finally using zsh and this is no longer bugging me

Comment: Is the repeat printing of the prompt "test_dir $ " and of the command "cd dir_"  also caused by the TAB key being pressed?

Comment: (don't repeatedly press tab...) Tab completion is usually configurable. However, this is not a programming question and should be posted to either [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) for proper answer.

Comment: Zsh's completion is far more advanced than Bash's. Bash can never print the completion candidates without moving the cursor (that's to say without reprinting the prompt).

Comment: bash does not have a global setting for this but it can be achieved in a per-command way which is obviously not practical for use.

Comment: @shellter ok, thanks. I wasn't sure which site to post it on, searched before posting and found a bunch of bash questions here, figured i'd just put it here.

Comment: @EmilyE. thanks, i had a feeling that would be the answer, but just wanted to see if i missed something.

Answer (score 2):

Add these two lines to your bashrc

```
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
bind 'TAB:menu-complete'
```

and you should be ok..But i see you have already moved to zsh.

More about [bind(a bash built-in)](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/bind.htm):

```
bind [-lpsvPSVX] [-m keymap] [-f filename] [-q name] [-u name]
     [-r keyseq] [-x keyseq:shell-command] 
     [keyseq:readline-function | readline-command]
```

Comment: Thank-you for this answer @hardeep! I too was getting very annoyed by this answer but didn't want to change shells just for this purpose.